# How to perform encodeURI on each element, before performing join on the entire array?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array variable

```
fruits=['banana','apple+juice'];
```

If I perform join, I will the following output

```
fruits.join(",")
```

> "banana,apple+juice"

My expectation is, each element should be performed `encodeURIComponent`, before going through `join`.

May I know, how can I achieve so, so that I can get the following output?

> "banana,apple%2bjuice"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`fruits.map(encodeURIComponent).join()`

I think you need `encodeURIComponent`. By default `join` uses a `,` as a separator so you can omit.